# How do I get the position of my python flet window?

Tags: python, flutter, position, desktop-application

I've been working with the python flet package for a while and I'd like to know how to get my window's position. Does anyone know anything?

I googled but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this package before, but looking at the docs it seems that `window_top` and `window_left` on the root `Page` instance are what you're after (assuming this is a desktop app). See relevant docs here: https://flet.dev/docs/controls/page#window_top.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.window_center()
    page.window_width = 500
    page.window_height = 300

    page.update()


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**